# codeigniter-mysql and persian insertion

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i am using Codeigniter and mysql . when i insert a persian string into mysql via codeIgniter code, '?' will store in field per character.

what is wrong?

for example : 'سلام' ---> '????'

Comment: persian insertion - pure poetry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your table created with utf8 characterset?
Did you call mysql_set_charset to change the charset to utf8 before executing your query?

Read

- [UTF8, PHP and MySQL](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/)
- [Does your PHP/MySQL Speak Unicode](http://www.richnetapps.com/php-mysql-speak-unicode/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Codeigniter ,Actually some functions in codeigniter are just parsers.
But it makes it easier ,